# Stackdriver "Alert & Notification" in GCP using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am unable to set Alert & Notification in Stackdriver. Able to configure Notification channel and Uptime Check using Terraform. Below are the codes I am using.

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "basic" {
  display_name = "Test Notification Channel"
  type         = "email"
  labels = {
    email_address = "fakeid007@gmail.com"
  }
  project = "department1"
}
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "http" {
  display_name = "01 - Website uptime check [global]"
  timeout = "10s"
  period = "60s"
  project = "department1"

  http_check {
    path = "/"
    port = "80"
    mask_headers = null
    use_ssl = null
    validate_ssl = null
    request_method = "GET"
  }

  monitored_resource {
    type = "uptime_url"
    labels = {
      host = "35.184.98.16"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not able to figure out the below part, which is possible with manual intervention.

[image]

In the picture you can see that the notification channel I created with terraform is visible.

Request to help me automate the Alert & Notification also.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way of doing this through TF, gcloud or the API.

In the end I used the `google_monitoring_alert_policy` using a Monitoring Query Language query with the `condition_monitoring_query_language` block, along the lines of:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "some-uptime-monitor-policy" {
  display_name = "Some Uptime Monitor"
 
  conditions {
    display_name = "Some Site Unavailable"

    condition_monitoring_query_language {
        query = "fetch uptime_url | metric 'monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed' | filter (resource.host == 'somesite.com') | group_by 1m, [value_check_passed_count_true: count_true(value.check_passed)] | every 5m | condition value_check_passed_count_true < 1 '1'"
        duration = "60s" 
        }
    }
  }
```

I had several monitors which is why I went the `condition_monitoring_query_language` way, if you have one monitor you could use `condition_threshold` in its place.  I found I couldn't get what I wanted with `condition_threshold` due the multi site requirement

Comment: Your above code require one more parameter combiner = "" and I have used OR. When I execute my code alone with your code I get the following error:

Comment: Error 400: This 'group_by' aligner requires that the alignment window be the same as the alignment period, but its alignment window of 1m differs from the alignment period of 5m. The alignment window is either given as a parameter to the aligner is given in a subsequent 'window' table operation. The alignment period is set by subsequent 'every' table operation. This problem can be fixed by not explicitly giving the window, not explicitly giving the period, or making them both the same."